# IIS and Users in called services

Tags: authentication, iis

Posted byu/grugno87
18 minutes ago

Hello everyone! I'm a NOOOOOB of IIS and I have a strange problem: I developed an ASP.NET Core application that runs in IIS. When I open a DB connection via ODBC or I auhenticate to AD through LDAP, I noticed that the username is not the one specified in the ODBC or in the LDAP authentication C# command. The User is the name of the PC where IIs runs (it looks like a machine user).

What's wrong? How can I tell IIS to not change the usernames of services?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 There are quite a few differences.

Comment: Yes! but if I ca't manage rights of the machine, how can I avoid that IIS changes the user specified in appsettings with the one that is running the asp instance?

Comment: If you don't have enough permissions, you should not be able to change the user.

Comment: This is exactly my problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I have asked to IT provide an identity that can query LDAP. It works but it is not the definitive answer of the problem.
ASAP I'll try with impersonation